# Draw line: retrieve the covered pixels

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4

I want to draw a line on a widget:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class LineLabel(QtGui.QLabel):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(LineLabel,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(100,100)
        self.setMaximumSize(100,100)

    def paintEvent(self,e):
        painter=QtGui.QPainter(self)
        pen = QtGui.QPen()
        pen.setWidth(5)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawLine(10,10,90,90)
        painter.end()

def test():
    form = QtGui.QWidget()
    label = LineLabel(form)
    form.show()
    return form

import sys
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window =test()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What is the best way to get a list of the pixels that are covered by the line?

Update from the comments:

- I don't need to know the pixels directly in between the start and end point but all those pixels that are changed to black (which are more pixels because the line has a certain width).
- My overall goal is a fast way to know which pixels on the widget are black. Iterating over the pixels of the image and querying the color is much slower than reading the color value from a list in which the colors are stored: For me 1.9 seconds for an image with 1 million pixels to 0.23 seconds for a list with 1 million entries. Therefore I must update that list after every change of the image on the widget such as by drawing a line.
- Answers that refer to a QGraphicsItem in a QGraphicsScene are also helpful.

Comment: This answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12362480/2531279

Comment: Indeed that is exactly the same question. The reference to QImage.scanLine helps but still the answer is unsatisfactory because iterating over the pixels is really slow. Compared to the answer, restricting the area that is iterated over to the possible part of the image (defined by start and end point of the line) makes it faster.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a linear equation to find the point you want in the line. I think that there is no reference to a draw line.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QColor, QPaintEvent

m_nInitialX = 0.0
m_nInitialY = 0.0


# my line abstraction
class MyLine:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = .0, .0, .0, .0
    width = .0
    px, py = (.0, .0)
    draw_point = False

    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2, width):
        self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2 = (x1, y1, x2, y2)
        self.width = width

    def is_in_line(self, x, y):
        # mark a position in the line
        m = (self.y2 - self.y1) / (self.x2 - self.x1)
        print(m*(x-self.x1)-(y-self.y1))
        if abs((m*(x-self.x1) - (y-self.y1))) <= self.width/2:
            self.draw_point = True
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def add_red_point(self, x, y):
        self.px, self.py = (x, y)

    def draw(self, widget):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(widget)
        pen = QtGui.QPen()
        pen.setWidth(self.width)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawLine(self.x1, self.y1, self.y2, self.y2)

        if self.draw_point:
            pen.setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0))
            painter.setPen(pen)
            painter.drawPoint(self.px, self.py)
        painter.end()


line = MyLine(10, 10, 90, 90, width=10)  # <-- my line abstraction


class LineLabel(QtGui.QLabel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LineLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(100, 100)
        self.setMaximumSize(100, 100)

    # always redraw when needed
    def paintEvent(self, e):
        print("draw!")
        line.draw(self)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        # mark clicked position in line
        m_nInitialX = event.pos().x()
        m_nInitialY = event.pos().y()
        if line.is_in_line(m_nInitialX, m_nInitialY):
            line.add_red_point(m_nInitialX, m_nInitialY)
            self.repaint()


def test():
    form = QtGui.QWidget()
    label = LineLabel(form)
    form.show()
    return form

import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = test()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I hope that PyQt offers a solution. In my example the line has a certain width so that just interpolating between the two endpoints of the line (e.g. with the Bresenham algorithm) is not the full solution. In a more general problem (not described in the example) the line might not be solid but dashed or it will not be a straight line but a more complex shape. I think PyQt should know which pixels are covered by the line because it must tell the graphics driver to make these pixels black.

Comment: Got your point. But when you want to make any change to a plotted graph, the usual way is to redraw the whole canvas. that´s why we usually keep an abstraction of the primitives, for the redraw purpose.

Comment: BTW. I found an answer to another question that may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368947/drawing-a-line-consisting-of-multiple-points-using-pyqt?rq=1

Comment: In that thread the program stores the pixels in a list and shall draw them. This is the other way round and might be easy. What I want to do generally is keeping records of the pixels of the image in a list for later reading; this list must be updated when a line is drawn. I have just checked that reading a pixel from the list is almost ten times faster than reading the pixel from the image. The worst working solution is iterating over the image pixels that are possibly part of the line and reading their value; this is time-consuming, of course.

Comment: I can´t figure out what are you trying to do. but that was a "bitmap" solution, but you can always use the parametric solution, just like games do. keeping track of the primitives parameters. and doing the redraw through primitives as i said in the first place, This is the most efficient way.  Reading the video memory was possible in the past but is not practical today. Sorry if I was unable to help.

Comment: Sorry but calculating all pixels that are part of the line is really cumbersome. In cases of wide lines or dashed lines doing this is even much more complicated. However, the result would be what I want to get automatically.